# Can a thor script can invoke itself

Tags: ruby, thor

I'm trying to figure whether it is possible for `thor` to invoke itself

Assuming like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require 'optparse'


class Thrasher < Thor
  include Thor::Actions

  def self.source_root
    File.dirname(__FILE__)
  end

  def thrash
    say 'something over here'
  end
end

Thrasher.start thrash
```

Can I achieve this in any way in thor, `backtick` and `system` command are available but can I do it purely via thor way.

Comment: Just found this now. I don't quite understand your question. If you want to do what's in your code sample, you can specify a default command with the method [`default_command`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor#default_command-class_method) and you can also call your own methods anywhere within your class...